# Implication of weak-$^*$ convergence in $L^\infty(0,T;V)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I've got a (hopefully) small problem with the following setting: Let $V,H,V'$ be a Gelfand-Triple ($V$ be seperable and reflexive), $\lbrace u_j \rbrace_j \in L^\infty(0,T;V)$ and $u_j(0) = u_{0j}$ be bounded with

\begin{align}
u_j \to u \text{ weakly star in } L^\infty(0,T;V).
\end{align}

Then $u_j(0) \to u_{0} =u(0)$ weakly in $V$.

Because of the boundness of $u_{0j}$ we can extract a weakly converging subsequence. But why is the limit $u_0$?

Thanks in advance, FFoDWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not hold. Take $V = H = \mathbb{R}$ and
$$u_j(t) = \begin{cases} j \, t & \text{if } t < 1/j, \\ 1 &\text{else}.\end{cases}$$
Then, $u_j \to 1$ weakly in $L^\infty(0,1)$ but $u_j(0) = 0 \not\to 1 = u(0)$.

By the way, for arbitrary $u \in L^\infty(0,T;V)$, the value $u(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little bit confused, though. Are there any results, if we've got a weak convergence of the derivatives?

Comment: Yes. If the derivative converges weak-*, the function itself converges uniformly.